# Haskell. Trouble with list of lists

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

I have list of lists of `Int` and I need to add an `Int` value to the last list from the list of lists. How can I do this? My attempt is below

```
f :: [[Int]] -> [Int] -> Int -> Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
f xs [] cur done total = [[]]
f xs xs2 cur done total = do 
  if total >= length xs2 then 
    xs
  else 
    if done == fib cur then
      f (xs ++ [[]]) xs2 (cur + 1) 0 total
    else
      f ((last xs) ++ [[xs2!!total]]) xs2 cur (done + 1) (total + 1)
```

The problem is:
We have a list `A` of Int 

And we need to slpit it on `N` lists `B_1 ,..., B_n` , length of `B_i` is i-th Fibonacci  number.

If we have list `[1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7]` (`xs2` in my code)
The result should be `[[1] , [2] , [3 , 4] , [5 , 6 , 7]]`

Comment: It's unclear to me what you aim to do. What are `cur`, `done` and `total` doing here?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I suspect most of the code as written is a red herring. Just looking at this snippet from the last line, `((last xs) ++ [[xs2!!total]])`, and matching that up with the question as asked, it seems clear to me what RicUfa is confused about. It seems kind of tricky to explain the mistake clearly (and explain how to fix it clearly), though...

Comment: This is additional parameters from a problem. I need to I need to add `xs2 !! total` to `last xs`.

Comment: @RicUfa: can you show some sample input/output to demonstrate what you aim to do?

Comment: My friend want me to help with home work. This is my first haskell program, so I am sorry if I'm asking something stupid)

Comment: @RicUfa: it is not stupid. But it would be nice if you demonstrate clearly what you want to do. What should be the output given the two lists are `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]` and `[7,8]`?

Comment: I have added an example to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way to deal with problems like this is to separate the problem into sub-problems. In this case, you want to change the last item in a list. The way you want to change it is by adding an item to it.

First let's tackle changing the last item of a list. We'll do this by applying a function to the last item, but not to any other items.

```
onLast :: [a] -> (a -> a) -> [a]
onLast xs f = go xs
  where
    go [] = []
    go [x] = [f x]
    go (x:xs) = x:go xs
```

You want to change the last item in the list by adding an additional value, which you can do with `(++ [value])`.

Combining the two with the value you want to add (`xs2!!total`) we get

```
(onLast xs (++ [xs2!!total]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You approach uses a `do` block, this is kind of weird since `do` blocks are usually used for *monads*. Furthermore it is rather unclear what `cur`, `done` and `total` are doing. Furthermore you use `(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a` and `length :: [a] -> Int`. The problem with these functions is that these run in *O(n)*, so it makes the code inefficient as well.

Based on changed specifications, you want to *split* the list in buckets with length the *Fibonacci numbers*. In that case the signature should be:

```
f :: [a] -> [[a]]
```

because as input you give a list of numbers, and as output, you return a list of numbers. We can then implement that as:

```
f :: [a] -> [[a]]
f = g 0 1
    where g _ _ [] = []
          g a b xs = xa : g b (a+b) xb
              where (xa,xb) = splitAt b xs
```

This generates:

```
*Main> f [1,2,3,4,5,6]
[[1],[2],[3,4],[5,6]]
*Main> f [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
[[1],[2],[3,4],[5,6,7]]
*Main> f [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
[[1],[2],[3,4],[5,6,7],[8]]
*Main> f [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
[[1],[2],[3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9]]
```

The code works as follows: we state that `f = g 0 1` so we pass the arguments of `f` to `g`, but `g` also gets an `0` and a `1` (the first Fibonacci numbers).

Each iteration `g` checks whether we reached the end of the list. If so, we return an empty list as well. Otherwise we determine the last Fibonacci number that far (`b`), and use a `splitAt` to obtain the first `b` elements of the list we process, as well as the remainder. We then emit the first part as head of the list, and for the tail we calculate the next Fibonacci number and pass that to `g` with the tail of `splitAt`.

Answer (score 0):

```
f :: [[Int]] -> Int -> [[Int]]                                                                                                                                                                                                   
f [] _ = []                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
f xs i = (take n xs) ++ [[x + i | x <- last xs]]                                                                                                                                                                                 
    where n = (length xs) - 1                                                                                                                                                                                                    
          last = head . (drop n)
```

For example,

```
*Main> f [[1, 2, 3], [], [4, 5, 6]] 5
[[1,2,3],[],[9,10,11]]
*Main> f [[1, 2, 3]] 5
[[6,7,8]]
*Main> f [] 3
```